# UWP Grid.ContextFlyout not opening

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In my UWP application, I've a list view in my main window and I've a secondary window. Each list view item in my list view is a `Grid` and I've `Grid.ContextFlyout` for the grid. The ContextFlyout contains a `MenuFlyout` with 4 `MenuFlyoutItem`.

I open my application, in the main window list view, I right click an item. I see the ContextFlyout opening and the `EventHandler<object> Opened` getting triggered.

Now, I open my app's secondary window and close the main window. Again I open my app's main window by opening my app from the start menu.

Now, If I right click the same item in the list view that I clicked before, I could see the `EventHandler<object> Opened` getting triggered, but the context flyout is not opening in the UI.

This issue occurs only in the above explained scenario(1. open the app, 2. right click the item, 3. open secondary window, 4. close main window, 5.open the main window of the app again from start menu, 6.right click the item)

Below is my Grid

```
<Grid
    Name="RootGrid">
    <Grid.ContextFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout
            x:Name="OptionsFlyout"
            Opening="Flyout_Opening" 
            Opened="Flyout_Opened"
            Closed="Flyout_Closed">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Name="Item1"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Name="Item2"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Name="Item3"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Name="Item4"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Grid.ContextFlyout>
    <TextBlock Text="MyGridItem"/>
</Grid>
```

In my `App.xaml.cs` I am using the below code in `OnLaunched` method to recover my main window

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunOnUIThread(async () =>
    {
      tryShow = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(ApplicationView.GetApplicationViewIdForWindow(CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().CoreWindow), ViewSizePreference.Default, e.CurrentlyShownApplicationViewId, ViewSizePreference.Default);
    });
}
```

Am I missing anything while opening/recovering my main window which is closed before? Or is there anything that could be done to fix this issue?

Below is the github link for the sample app that I created to reproduce this issue.
[UWP Grid Context Menu](https://github.com/sethubala16/UWPGridContextMenu.git)

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I have edited my question with the github link for my sample app to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This issue occurs only in the above explained scenario(1. open the app, 2. right click the item, 3. open secondary window, 4. close main window, 5.open the main window of the app again from start menu, 6.right click the item)

I could reproduce this issue. I've reported to the relevant team. You also could submit it in our Feedback Hub.

Here's a workaround for you. You could use `FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout` instead of 'ContextFlyout'. You just need to register the `RightTapped` event of the Grid and add a little code like the following:

```
<Grid Name="RootGrid" Height="50" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Green" RightTapped="RootGrid_RightTapped">
       <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout
        x:Name="OptionsFlyout"
            Opening="MenuFlyout_Opening" 
            Opened="FolderOptionsFlyout_Opened"
            Closed="FolderOptionsFlyout_Closed">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Name="Item1" Text="Item1"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Name="Item2" Text="Item2"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Name="Item3" Text="Item3"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Name="Item4" Text="Item4"/>
             </MenuFlyout>
       </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
       <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" Height="150" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

```
private void RootGrid_RightTapped(System.Object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
    var menu = Flyout.GetAttachedFlyout(fe);
    menu.ShowAt(fe);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs closing the main window should just hide it.
From [Show multiple views for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views)

"If secondary views are open, the main view’s window can be hidden – for example, by clicking the close (x) button in the window title bar - but its thread remains active."

Starting with 1703 you can have the main window handle the close request event.  Upon close, the code can switch to the secondary window while hiding the main window.  Then tell the system that you have handled the close yourself by setting the Handled property to true.

In the appxmanifest add the confirmAppClose capability.

```
<Capabilities>
     <Capability Name="internetClient" />
     <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose"/> 
</Capabilities>
```

Now handle the CloseRequested event.  Here's what the code looks like:

```
    private int MainViewId;
    private int SecondViewId;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested += MainPage_CloseRequested;
    }

    private async void MainPage_CloseRequested(object sender, SystemNavigationCloseRequestedPreviewEventArgs e)
    {   
        // Switch to Secondary window, Hide main window                          
        await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(
                SecondViewId,
                MainViewId,
                ApplicationViewSwitchingOptions.ConsolidateViews);

        // The close was handled, don't do anything else
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private async void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        var newCoreApplicationView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();             

        await newCoreApplicationView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            SecondViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;

            Window SecondWindow = Window.Current;
            var frame = new Frame();
            frame.Navigate(typeof(Assets.SecondWindow));
            SecondWindow.Content = frame;
            SecondWindow.Activate();
        });

        await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(SecondViewId, ViewSizePreference.Default);
    }
```